# Does MS ODBC SQL driver install SQLcmd.exe?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, msodbcsql17

I can’t seem to find the SQLcmd.exe utility after installing msodbcsql.msi (SQL driver 17). According to MS docs
“The ODBC driver comes with tools such as sqlcmd and bcp.”

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

So why is there a separate msi for the command line utilities aka SQLcmd & Bcp? Am I crazy or shouldn’t SQLcmd.exe also be installed with ODBC msi per the documentation? My program needs to install ODBC + SQLcmd.exe and it would be helpful to have both installed in one swoop. Any ideas?

Comment: Just tested this in a sandbox, SQLcmd is nowhere to be found when everything was checked for full installation.

Comment: Frustrating. I supposed the documentation is just wrong. Thanks for confirming @Preben Huybrechts .

Comment: I think you mis-interpret the documentation - and it is poorly worded. The "comes with" concept should probably be evaluated in the opposite direction. That is, the sql server tools include the driver.